# tinyMCE.execCommand on two different textarea on a single page

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

This is a JavaScript function to replace text on textarea with tinyMCE.

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, text)
```

In my page I have two textareas with tinyMCE and I want to modify only one.

I have tried to do some research, but the research not solved this problem.

Comment: Solved, added get between tinyMCE. and .execCommand

Comment: It is recommended to post answer to your own question so others can benefit from it :)